# Get current directory name in htaccess and prevent redirection

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this **.htaccess** file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
DirectorySlash On
RewriteEngine On

# Remove trailing slash for non directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /mydir%1/$1 [R,L=303]

# Make direct files accessible
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^base.php.*$
RewriteRule ^([^\n]+)|(.*)$ base.php?___ROUTE=$1 [QSA,END]
```

Which having following redirection behaviors:

1. ✔️ `d.com/mydir` → `d.com/mydir/`
2. ✔️ `d.com/mydir/nothing` → ***run***
3. ✔️ `d.com/mydir/nothing/` → `d.com/mydir/nothing`
4. ❌ `d.com/mydir/exist_dir` → `d.com/mydir/exist_dir/?___ROUTE=exist_dir`
5. ❌ `d.com/mydir/exist_dir/` → ***run***
6. ✔️ `d.com/mydir/exist_file.css` → ***run***
7. ✔️ `d.com/mydir/exist_file.css/` → `d.com/mydir/exist_file.css`

> By ***run*** I mean It respond file contents or execute `base.php?___ROUTE=$1`

Now I have a problem and a question

**Problem**:

I don't know how to fix redirection number 4.

Number 5 should redirect to `d.com/mydir/exist_dir`.

And number 4 should execute `base.php?___ROUTE=$1` instead of redirection

‌

**Question**:

How can I use current directory name in `.htaccess` instead of writing it's name in each project?

I mean `/mydir` in `RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /mydir%1/$1 [R,L=303]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I did it.*

## How to fix redirection on non-directory with ending slash

First,  I've made an `ENV Variable` for *removed trailing slash path* then use it in `RewriteRule`.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
DirectorySlash On
RewriteEngine On

SetEnvIf Request_URI ^(.*)/$ CUSTOM_BASE_DIR=$1

# Remove trailing slash for non directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ %{ENV:CUSTOM_BASE_DIR} [R,L=303]

# Make direct files accessible
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^base.php.*$
RewriteRule ^([^\n]+)|(.*)$ base.php?___ROUTE=$1 [QSA,END]
```